# Can i use 'self' in classes on its own?

Tags: python, class, self

I have a `list` of objects of the Person class. This list includes myself, so I need to remove "**myself**" from the list.

It means I need to **remove the object** from the list **that calls this method**.

```
class Population:
    def __init__(self):
        self.people = list()

class Person:
    def __init__(self):
        self.friends_list = list()

    def make_friends(self, population, n):
        temp_list = population.copy()
        temp_list.remove(self)
        self.friends_list.extend(random.sample(temp_list,n))
```

my test:

```
per = Person()
per2 = Person()
per3 = Person()
per4 = Person()
per5 = Person()
pop = [per,per2,per3,per4,per5]
for per in pop:
    per.make_friends(pop, 2)
    print('ME: ',per)
    print(per.friends_list)
```

My tests run well, but there are general tests that check the code and they generate an error on this line:

```
try:
    stud_res = person.make_friends(population, count)
except Exception:
    print("\tPerson.make_friends() generated error")
    return
```

Can I use `self` in this way, and if not, how can I better remove "myself" from the list?

Comment: `self` is just a conventional name for the object that the method is bound to. Since it's an object like any other, you can do whatever you want with it, including removing it from a list. Did you try to do this? Did it throw an error? Or did it do something that made you think you can't do this? Please [edit] your question to include more details.

Answer (score 1):

It is a perfectly fine use case. By the way, note that you're overriding the builtin list.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. That was a simplified version of the code, in the original I made temp_list

Answer (score 1):

To use `self`, you have to share a list collection between instances of a `Person`-class. In that case this collection should be declared as a class attribute or global list variable (not an instance attribute).

These samples of code are working:

with global list variable:

```
class Person:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def make_friends(self, list):
        list.remove(self)

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name


p1 = Person("Joe")
p2 = Person("Barack")

the_list = []
the_list.append(p1)
the_list.append(p2)

p1.make_friends(the_list)

print(the_list)
```

With class attribute:

```
class Person2:
    class_list = []

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        Person2.class_list.append(self)

    def make_friends(self):
        Person2.class_list.remove(self)

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name


p1 = Person2("Joe")
p2 = Person2("Barack")
print(Person2.class_list)
p1.make_friends()
print(Person2.class_list)
```

EDIT:
Variable 3 when a list of people is inside another class.
For accessing a list inside another class you could use attribute name or public method to get it if implemented:

```
class ClassWithList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.list_collection = []

    def get_list(self):
        return self.list_collection


class_with_list = ClassWithList()


class Person:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def make_friends(self, list):
        list.remove(self)

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name


p1 = Person("Joe")
p2 = Person("Barack")
# using implemented get-method of instance list attribute
class_with_list.get_list().append(p1)
class_with_list.get_list().append(p2)
print(class_with_list.get_list())
p1.make_friends(class_with_list.get_list())

print(class_with_list.get_list())

# instance list attribute of class`ClassWithList
print(class_with_list.list_collection)
p2.make_friends(class_with_list.list_collection)
print(class_with_list.list_collection)
```

Comment: there is probably a mistake - the list of people is an instance attribute of another class, and I can't change that in any way
How can I delete the object in this case?

Comment: could you provide a minimal working example? Providing MWE is the best way to overcome misunderstandings

Comment: `the list of people is an instance attribute of another class` -- in that case this class should provide a public method to get a list instance inside him

Comment: @redflag check the update of my answer

Comment: I'm sorry I wrote so little, but I already edited the question